# Uniform distribution, estimates, MVUEs and Cramer Rao Lower Bound

Tags: estimation, inference, uniform-distribution, unbiased-estimator, fisher-information

As a revision exercise, I'm going through all of the distributions and deriving estimators. I've gotten to the $Uniform$. I've worked out the MLE and MOM estimators. The next step is to consider whether they attain the Cramer Rao Lower Bound.

Is it right to say that we can't work this out for the uniform distribution as the Fisher Information cannot be sensibly calculated? I've seen this written in a few places but don't quite understand the reasons why. I read that it applies to $Uni(0,\infty)$ and $Uni(\theta,\theta+1)$ because they are not "regular", but does it apply to all uniform distributions? What does "regular" mean in this context?

Please could someone help with the intuition for this (and/or point me in the direction of some good resources that discuss it)?

Comment: 'Regular' refers to certain [regularity conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Regularity_conditions); you can find more details in standard textbooks. So the $U(0,\theta)$ and $U(\theta,\theta+1)$ distributions for example do not satisfy the regularity conditions. Some discussion can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2742267/321264) regarding Cramer-Rao bound.

Comment: ... Hence the CR lower bound is not applicable in these cases.